# Why am I getting a null error with this JSP code?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I am getting a null error with my JSP code and I can not figure out why.

When i remove the jsp:setProperty lines the code works fine, and then if I add them in and refresh the page it works fine but if I start the server with the lines already in I get a null error, even when I set the default input box values to 0;

JSP File:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"

pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="beans.JavaBean"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Sum</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="InterestingFile.jsp">
      <jsp:useBean id="SumNumber" class="beans.JavaBean" />
      <label>Number 1: </label>
      <input type="text" name="num1Text"><jsp:setProperty name="SumNumber" property="num1" value='<%= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1Text")) %>' />
      <label>Number 2: </label>
      <input type="text" name="num2Text"><jsp:setProperty name="SumNumber" property="num2" value='<%= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2Text")) %>' />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      <input type="reset" value="Reset"/><jsp:setProperty name="SumNumber" property="sum" value="0" />
    </form>
    <jsp:setProperty name="SumNumber" property="sum" value='<%= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1Text")) + Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2Text")) %>' />
    <p>Result: <jsp:getProperty name="SumNumber" property="sum" /></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Files] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [/InterestingFile.jsp] at line [17]

14:     <form action="InterestingFile.jsp">
15:       <jsp:useBean id="SumNumber" class="beans.JavaBean" />
16:       <label>Number 1: </label>
17:       <input type="text" name="num1Text"><jsp:setProperty name="SumNumber" property="num1" value='<%= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1Text")) %>' />
18:       <label>Number 2: </label>
19:       <input type="text" name="num2Text"><jsp:setProperty name="SumNumber" property="num2" value='<%= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2Text")) %>' />
20:       <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
    at org.apache.jsp.MiniAdd_jsp._jspService(InterestingFile_jsp.java:141)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1699)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: the value you are trying to cast isn't set. So, it's null, and null is not a value that can be  turned into a numeric value

Comment: @Stultuske How do i set the value in this case? I tried using value="0" in each of the input tags but that did not work. Do I need to use declarations?

Comment: When you're initially rendering the page `request.getParameter("num1Text")` is bound to return `null` because there'd be no such parameter. So you need to handle that, i.e. if the parameter doesn't exist yet you need to set a default.

Comment: @Thomas How do I set a default value for those fields?

Comment: I didn't use JSPs in a while (and when I did I tried not to use scriptlets) but try `<%= request.getParameter("num1Text") != null ? Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1Text")) : 0 %>` (alternatively try a scriptlet to actually do an if-else or better use JSTL's `<c:if>` etc. to render different property tags in each case).

Comment: @Thomas that worked. How would I do the same thing but for the sum variable on line 32? I tried     <jsp:setProperty name="SumNumber" property="sum" value='<%= request.getParameter("num2Text") != null && request.getParameter("num2Text") != null ? Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1Text")) + Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2Text")) %>' />

Comment: Try to learn how to use beans and their methods in JSPs and then move those calculations there. You _could_ do it in a scriptlet but that can get quite complex and thus ugly, hard to read and hard to maintain.

Comment: @Thomas This is for an assignment. Im just trying to make it work. Not so worried about how hard it is to read.

Comment: Well, your approach shoudl work but you missed the ` : defaultValue` portion of the ternary expression. However, if I were the instructor giving the assignment I'd very much care about readability.

Comment: @Thomas I still cant get that line to work. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: As I said I havent used JSPs in a while so I can't provide a definite answer and you might be required to do some more research (since you're learning you should do that anyway). One more try: you're already setting the `num1` and `num2` properties of bean `SumNumber`, so you could try to access those. I'm not sure about scriptlets but with expressions you could try `value="${SumNumber.num1 + SumNumber.num2}"` or something like that.